# Running Max ArrayFormula for Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, max, vlookup, array-formulas

I have a list of numbers entered manually:

```
1
100
100
10
1
1000
10
1000
1
1000
100
10
```

I'd like to get the running max - the max value for each sub-array of the initial numbers array. By sub-array I mean numbers from `[A1]` to `[A2]`, from `[A1]` to `[A3]`, from `[A1]` to `[A4]`, etc.

The result would be as follows:

```
1
100
100
100
100
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
```

More entries may be added to the initial list of numbers.

---

Using the bountied answer, here's a speed test with 100500 rows:

[image]

This does not include the [latest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74317600/)

Comment: The test is non randomized and biased due to repeated values. It should be tested on A1`=SEQUENCE(100500)`

Comment: @TheMaster, thanks. Maybe I also had to do tests in separate Sheets, etc. I have to be a scientist =) BTW do you have a good idea of improving the solution? `Lambda` should be the answer?

Comment: I maybe wrong, but I expect Tom's answer to be faster. Player0's answer removes duplicates with `SORTN`. That's why it's faster in your data. It only does a subset of operations that Tom's does, because it removes dupes beforehand. If the data doesn't have dupes, I expect significant differences(I haven't tested, so I maybe completely wrong). `Lambda should be the answer?` it should, but I'm not sure whether I can keep the number of operations down to accommodate 100k rows.

Comment: Also, the script shouldn't fail. Maybe try removing `INDEX` and send the array directly.

Comment: @TheMaster, thanks again. I've just added new answer: `=SCAN(A2,A2:A,LAMBDA(ini,v,if(ini>v,ini,v)))`. IMHO = this one became the best now. Tested. Works fast for 100K rows. Tests: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JofiT3fYxhSerQp93LfNYyi4R9gwGXNGIJL9YWgY87M/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thanks for the edits @TheMaster . My main aim is to strive for a reasonable chronological order between questions and answers, such that new readers are not confused my material that is shown in an unexpected normal ordering.

Comment: @halfer  Sure Np. I agree that a answer is a much better place for benchmarks. Even now, it looks a little inappropriate.  But in that specific answer, it really made no sense, as it didn't include the latest formula(`SCAN`) tests. The question was a better place compared to that answer. But a separate answer or complete removal(as the tests are 1.biased(IMO) in the first place and 2.not updated with latest formulas) would be much more appropriate. But I'll leave that choice to OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @TheMaster for notes. Now the best solution is:

`=SCAN(A3,A3:A,LAMBDA(ini,v,if(ini>v,ini,v)))`

The `ini`tial value is compared against each current `v`alue and the max for each iteration is returned by `SCAN`.

I've tested it [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JofiT3fYxhSerQp93LfNYyi4R9gwGXNGIJL9YWgY87M/edit#gid=0). It works fast for 100K rows.

---

`Lambda` solution works better because it needs to operate each cell one time. The complexity = the number of cells operated. While the other solutions use formulas that "look back" to previus values.

The [scripting solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70578825/) may also work fine, but native formulas does not waste time on "loading" data into the Sheet. Original tests were done before the `Lambda` function appeared in Sheets.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @TheMaster, thanks to your notes. I've tried to explain this as for my understandimg. Feel free to edit my answer or add your own if you want to improve this.

Answer (score 3):

how about:

```
=INDEX(VLOOKUP(ROW(A:A), FILTER(
 SORTN({ROW(A:A), A:A}, 9^9, 2, 2, 1), IFNA(SORTN(ROW(A:A), 9^9, 2, A:A, 1)<
 QUERY(SORTN(ROW(A:A), 9^9, 2, A:A, 1), "offset 1", ), 1)), 2, 1))
```

this will not work... see update bellow

[image]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=INDEX(VLOOKUP(ROW(A:A), FILTER(SORT(SORTN({ROW(A:A), A:A}, 9^9, 2, 2, 1)), 
 COUNTIFS(UNIQUE(A:A), ">"&UNIQUE(A:A), 
 SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(A:A)+1), "<="&SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(A:A)+1))=0), 2, 1))
```

[image]

and to account for empty rows:

```
=INDEX(IF(A:A="",,VLOOKUP(ROW(A:A), 
 FILTER(SORT(SORTN(FILTER({ROW(A:A), A:A}, A:A<>""), 9^9, 2, 2, 1)), 
 COUNTIFS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A, A:A<>"")), ">"&UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A, A:A<>"")), 
 SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(A:A)), "<="&SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(A:A)))=0), 2, 1)))
```

[image]

Comment: I like it and guess performance looks better than DMAX `arrayformula`, suggested here: https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/running-max-in-google-sheets-array-formula/  . Congrats! Very clean and smart formula. I'll surely select it as a correct answer if no better proposition comes!

Comment: BTW is your deleted answer incorrect? `=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(A:A), SORTN({ROW(A:A), A:A}, 9^9, 2, 2, 1), 2, 1)))`

Comment: @MaxMakhrov yes, it is. it looks like correct one, but I managed to break it in certain scenarios.

Comment: @MaxMakhrov answer updated

Comment: Thanks! What if the range is `A3:A`? Some of the formulas may not work. I'll need to spend some time trying. `SORTN` option looked very promising.

Comment: `=INDEX(IF(A3:A="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(A3:A), SORTN(FILTER({ROW(A3:A), A3:A},A3:A), 9^9, 2, 2, 1), 2))))` seems to work, the formula is based on your basic idea with `SORTN`

Comment: @MaxMakhrov see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uMmD.png
and    https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgoRr.png

Comment: Thanks for the crash test. Here're my other tests: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rdXZGs1dqI1HYpiZeFnYqt7bhEKFthH38TFRPpSJcbA/edit#gid=797386721 . Interesting, this solution crashes too (https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/running-max-in-google-sheets-array-formula/). Your `FLATTEN` formula crashes when blank rows are added. I'm trying to fix it now.

Comment: @MaxMakhrov see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNlgW.png

Comment: Thanks. I'd change it to `=INDEX(IF(A3:A="",, QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 SEQUENCE(MATCH(9, 1/(A3:A<>"")))&"×"&IF(
 SEQUENCE(MATCH(9, 1/(A3:A<>"")))>=
 SEQUENCE(1, MATCH(9, 1/(A3:A<>""))), TRANSPOSE(
 INDIRECT("A"&row()&":A"&MATCH(9, 1/(A:A<>"")))), )), "×"), 
 "select max(Col2) group by Col1 label max(Col2)''")))`

Answer (score 2):

Can I put this one into the running, @Max?

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A:A="",,vlookup(row(A:A),
{if(countifs(A1:A,">"&A:A,row(A:A),"<"&row(A:A))=0,row(A:A)),A:A}
,2)))
```

[image]

You can use this if there are intervening blank cells:

```
 =ArrayFormula(if(A:A="",,vlookup(row(A:A),
{if((countifs(A1:A,">"&A:A,row(A:A),"<"&row(A:A))=0)*(A:A<>""),row(A:A)),A:A}
,2)))
```

The original formula (if there are no blanks between non-blanks) can be simplified to

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(row(A:A),
{if(countifs(A1:A,">"&A:A,row(A:A),"<"&row(A:A))=0,row(A:A)),A:A}
,2))
```

Comment: Nice shot, Tom! I'm trying to crash it with no success yet. My tests: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rdXZGs1dqI1HYpiZeFnYqt7bhEKFthH38TFRPpSJcbA/edit#gid=797386721

Comment: Hi Tom, your answer is the shorter formula, but I've made a test with a sheet of 100500 rows and tested the speed. Appeared `SORTN` option worked faster, and I've decided to reward another answer. I'm grateful for your answer, thank you very much, but unfortunately have to give a bounty for another A.

Comment: That's fair, thanks Max.

Answer (score 1):

custom formula sample:

```
=INDEX(IF(A3:A="","",
  runningTotal(A3:A,4)))
```

[image]

[sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rdXZGs1dqI1HYpiZeFnYqt7bhEKFthH38TFRPpSJcbA/edit#gid=1903199015)

[source code](https://github.com/Max-Makhrov/GoogleSheets/blob/master/sheets/customFunctions/runningTotal.gs)

[related](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/162059/118810)

code:

```
/**
 * Get running total for the array of numbers
 * by makhrov.max@gmail.com
 * 
 * @param {array} numbers The array of numbers
 * @param {number} total_types (1-dafault) sum, (2) avg, (3) min, (4) max, (5) count;
 *                  1-d array or number
 * @param {number} limit number of last values to count next time. 
 *                 Set to 0 (defualt) to take all values
 * @param {array} keys (optional) array of keys. Function will group result by keys
 * @return The hex-code of cell background & font color
 * @customfunction
 */
function runningTotal(numbers, total_types, limit, keys) { 
  
  // possible types to return
  var oTypes = {
    '1': 'sum',
    '2': 'avg',
    '3': 'min',
    '4': 'max',
    '5': 'count'
  }
  // checks and defaults
  var errPre = ' ';
  if( typeof numbers != "object" ) {
    numbers = [ [numbers] ];
  }
  total_types = total_types || [1];
  if( typeof total_types != "object" ) {
    total_types = [ total_types ];
  }
  if( keys && typeof keys != "object" ) {
    keys = [ [keys] ];
  }
  if (keys) {
    if (numbers.length !== keys.length) {
      throw errPre + 'Numbers(' + 
        numbers.length + 
        ') and keys(' + 
        keys.length + 
        ') are of different length'; }
  }
  // assign types
  var types = [], type, k;
  for (var i = 0; i < total_types.length; i++) {
    k = '' + total_types[i];
    type = oTypes[k];
    if (!type) {
      throw errPre + 'Unknown total_type = ' + k;
    }
    types.push(type);
  }
  limit = limit || 0;
  if (isNaN(limit)) {
    throw errPre + '`limit` is not a Number!';
  }
  limit = parseInt(limit);

  // calculating running totals
  var result = [], 
    subres = [], 
    nodes = {}, 
    key = '-', 
    val;
  var defaultNode_ = {
      values: [],
      count: 0,
      sum: 0,
      max: null,
      min: null,
      avg: null,
      maxA: Number.MIN_VALUE,
      maxB: Number.MIN_VALUE,
      maxC: Number.MIN_VALUE,
      minA: Number.MAX_VALUE,
      minB: Number.MAX_VALUE,
      minC: Number.MAX_VALUE
    };
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    val = numbers[i][0];
    // find correct node
    if (keys) { key = keys[i][0]; }
    node = nodes[key] || 
      JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(defaultNode_));
    /**
     * For findig running Max/Min
     * sourse of algorithm
     * https://www.geeksforgeeks.org
     * /sliding-window-maximum-maximum-of-all-subarrays-of-size-k/
     */
    // max
    //reset first second and third largest elements
    //in response to new incoming elements
    if (node.maxA<val) {
      node.maxC = node.maxB;
      node.maxB = node.maxA;
      node.maxA = val;
    } else if (node.maxB<val) {
      node.maxC = node.maxB;
      node.maxB = val;
    } else if (node.maxC<val) {
      node.maxC = val;
    }
    // min
    if (node.minA>val) {
      node.minC = node.minB;
      node.minB = node.minA;
      node.minA = val;
    } else if (node.minB>val) {
      node.minC = node.minB;
      node.minB = val;
    } else if (node.minC>val) {
      node.minC = val;
    }

    // if limit exceeds
    if (limit !== 0 && node.count === limit) {
      //if the first biggest we earlier found
      //is matching from the element that
      //needs to be removed from the subarray
      if(node.values[0]==node.maxA) {
        //reset first biggest to second and second to third
        node.maxA = node.maxB;
        node.maxB = node.maxC;
        node.maxC = Number.MIN_VALUE;
        if (val <= node.maxB) {
          node.maxC = val;
        }
      } else if (node.values[0]==node.maxB) {
        node.maxB = node.maxC;
        node.maxC = Number.MIN_VALUE;
        if (val <= node.maxB) {
          node.maxC = val;
        }
      } else if (node.values[0]==node.maxC) {
        node.maxC = Number.MIN_VALUE;
        if (val <= node.maxB) {
          node.maxC = val;
        }
      } else if(node.values[0]==node.minA) {
        //reset first smallest to second and second to third
        node.minA = node.minB;
        node.minB = node.minC;
        node.minC = Number.MAX_VALUE;
        if (val > node.minB) {
          node.minC = val;
        }
      }
      if (node.values[0]==node.minB) {
        node.minB = node.minC;
        node.minC = Number.MAX_VALUE;
        if (val > node.minB) {
          node.minC = val;
        }
      } 
      if (node.values[0]==node.minC) {
        node.minC = Number.MAX_VALUE;
        if (val > node.minB) {
          node.minC = val;
        }
      }
      // sum
      node.sum -= node.values[0];
      // delete first value
      node.values.shift();
      // start new counter
      node.count = limit-1; 
    }
    // add new values
    node.count++;
    node.values.push(val);
    node.sum += val;
    node.avg = node.sum/node.count;
    node.max = node.maxA;
    node.min = node.minA;
    // remember entered values for the next loop
    nodes[key] = node;

    // get the result depending on 
    // selected total_types
    subres = [];
    for (var t = 0; t < types.length; t++) {
      subres.push(node[types[t]]);
    }
    result.push(subres);
  }
  // console.log(JSON.stringify(nodes, null, 4));
  return result;
}
```

Other solutions:

- [`DMAX` arrayformula](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/running-max-in-google-sheets-array-formula/)

Answer (score 1):

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(ROW(A1:A12)&"×"&
 IF(ROW(A1:A12)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A12)), TRANSPOSE(A1:A12), )), "×"), 
 "select max(Col2) group by Col1 label max(Col2)''"))
```

[image]

but to keep it fast:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 SEQUENCE(MATCH(9, 1/(A:A<>"")))&"×"&IF(
 SEQUENCE(MATCH(9, 1/(A:A<>"")))>=
 SEQUENCE(1, MATCH(9, 1/(A:A<>""))), TRANSPOSE(
 INDIRECT("A1:A"&MATCH(9, 1/(A:A<>"")))), )), "×"), 
 "select max(Col2) group by Col1 label max(Col2)''"))
```

[image]

and to account for empty rows:

```
=INDEX(IF(A:A="",, QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 SEQUENCE(MATCH(9, 1/(A:A<>"")))&"×"&IF(
 SEQUENCE(MATCH(9, 1/(A:A<>"")))>=
 SEQUENCE(1, MATCH(9, 1/(A:A<>""))), TRANSPOSE(
 INDIRECT("A1:A"&MATCH(9, 1/(A:A<>"")))), )), "×"), 
 "select max(Col2) group by Col1 label max(Col2)''")))
```

[image]

and yes, it works with `MIN`, `SUM`, `AVG` and `COUNT`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

ofc `COUNT` would be massive overkill tho

[image]